# Remove ListViewItem using its tag property and without a foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listview

I have a `ListView` on my User Control. I have put the `Id` of my object inside the `Tag` property of my `ListViewItem`s.

How can I remove an item from my `ListView` based on its `Tag` value without putting all items in a `foreach` loop? Is there a LINQ for this somehow?

Comment: Don't LINQ statements internally use a foreach loop to iterate the collection anyway? What I mean is that you have to iterate the collection anyway if you don't know the exact item in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
ListView.Remove(ListView.Items.First(item => item.Tag == id));
```

However enumeration will still take place..

Answer (score 2):

Use the overloaded Add method on ListView.Items that accepts a key as a first parameter. Then simply use RemoveByKey() on ListView.Items when removing.
See RemoveByKey() documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.removebykey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Object o = myListView.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Tag == theId);
if (o != null)
{
    myListView.Items.Remove(o);
}
```